# How to get value from Ext.data.Store ?

Tags: extjs

this is my code

```
var store = {
    user_store: new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'a/b/c',
        }),
        remoteSort: true,
        baseParams: {

        },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            totalProperty: 'total',
            root: 'root',
            fields: ['roles']
        })
    })
};
store.user_store.load();​
```

this is my json

```
{"roles":"2"}
```

I wnat to ask. How do I get the roles's value is "2".

(PS:Sorry,my English is not very well.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there is only one item in the response, you can add a callback function to the load method:

```
var store = {
    user_store: new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'a/b/c',
        }),
        remoteSort: true,
        baseParams: {

        },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            totalProperty: 'total',
            root: 'root',
            fields: ['roles']
        })
    })
};
store.user_store.load(function(){
    this.getAt(0).get('roles')
});​
```

If the the response consist of several items like: `[{"roles":"2"},{"roles":"1"}]`
you can iterate the store to retrieve all values.

```
store.user_store.load(function(){
    this.each(function(record){
       var roles = record.get('roles');
       // Do stuff with value
    });
});​
```

Comment: I use store.first().get('roles')                                  But TypeError: store.user_store.first is not a function why?

Comment: .first() is not included in 3.4. Try store.getAt(0) instead.

Comment: It is'not work. I try to solve my question. Maybe my question is "dealy question ". Because the method load is asynchronous. I guess that i should use callback() in load method.

Comment: Yes, you should try to fetch the value when the store is loaded. I've updated the answer.

Comment: carcel the answer is very helpful for me. Thanks.