# How to print (or alert) value from ExtJS store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am trying to get a value from an ExtJS store to use it in a variable. I tried to print it with console.log, following instructions from another questions answered here on StackOverflow and on Sencha forum, with no success. I am getting this error message on my first attempt:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

And this message on my second attempt:

> myView is not defined

where "myView" is the class name of this current window.

Here is my Store code:

```
myStore = this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                proxy:new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
                    url: "php/data.php"
                }),
            root: 'result',
            autoLoad: false,
            fields: [
                {name:'ID',type:'string',mapping:'ID'},
                {name:'NAME',type:'string',mapping:'NAME'}

            ]
        });
```

Here is how I am trying to get the values from store:

First attempt:

```
var vId = myStore.data.items[0].data.ID;
console.log(vId);
```

Second attempt:

```
store.storeDadosSol.load(function(){
                this.each(function(record){
                var vId = record.get('ID');
                // Do stuff with value
                console.log(vId);
                });
            });​
```

I am following these answers:

[Sencha Forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180764-how-to-read-a-record-value-from-a-store-into-a-variable)

[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396346/how-to-get-value-from-ext-data-store)

Any ideas? I am using ExtJS **version 3.2.1**

Comment: You will find store records in a store.load callback as stated in sencha docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load

Comment: Add load event for your store and then print it.

Comment: Thanks @fen1ksss, I used a callback function and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your myStore declaration uses

> `myStore = this.store =`

When you try to access the values from the store, are you in the same scope? Is myStore a global variable?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I find out that this load function was using a parameter that was been loaded after the store.load. I just put the parameter variable to be sent on page load and that solve the problem.